# How to cloane a git repository?

Tags: git, github-pages

I have created a repository in git. I need to create a clone of my repository on local system.
How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean "clone"?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/cloning-a-repository

Answer (score 0):

From your repository page on GitHub, click the green button labeled Clone or download, and in the “Clone with HTTPs” section, copy the URL for your repository. Next, on your local machine, open your bash shell and change your current working directory to the location where you would like to clone your repository

Answer (score 0):

You can clone a local git repository much like you would clone a remote repository:

```
git clone <local path to existing repository> <path to new cloned repository>
```

For example, if you have an existing repository in a folder named "existing_repository", you can create a cloned copy of it in "cloned_repository".

```
/projects $ git clone existing_repository cloned_repository
Cloning into 'cloned_repository'...
done.
/projects $
```

You could alternatively just copy the contents of the existing repository using your OS's recursive copy command.